# Snakemake suggestions on the workflow design to overcome the ambiguous rules

Tags: snakemake

I have two rules that are capable of producing the same output depending on the wildcard value and this causes the ambiguous rule exception.

 I read the documentation on http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=ruleorder#handling-ambiguous-rules about handling the ambiguous rule exceptions. 
It seems that the use of *rule order* could be the solution. However, the input of my rule *preprocess_zheng17* is depending on the output of the *simulate_data* rule. Therefore, if I use the `ruleorder: simulate_data  > preprocess_zheng17` then, the preprocess_zheng17 rule is never run. 
What I would like to do is to first run the *simulate_data* and then to run the *preprocess_zheng17* rule for each wildcard pairs. I am wondering what could be a good workflow design practice to cope with this problem. The rules are provided below.

```
rule preprocess_zheng17:
    input:
        loom_file = SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}.loom'
    params:
        transpose = False
    output:
        SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}_zheng17.loom'
    script: 
        "scripts/preprocess_zheng17.py"

rule simulate_data:
    input:
        sample_loom = HDF5_OUTPUT+'/{sample}.loom'
    params:
        group_prob = config['splat_simulate']['group_prob'],
        dropout_present = config['splat_simulate']['dropout_present']
    output:
        SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}.loom'
    script:
        "scripts/data_simulation.R"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does it help if you declare `simulate_data` first, and use `rules.simulate_data.output` as `input` for `preprocess_zheng17` ? Another thing to try would be to declare `wildcard_constraints` for `loc`, if you can.

Comment: Many thanks! I did not know about the wildcard_constraints. Having a regular expression for the wildcard values solved my problem. I have also altered many other rules in my pipeline with the wildcard constraints.
In general, I think it is a good practice to use the wildcard constraints where applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem does not come from the design but from the fact that the outputs of your two rules and the wildcards used cannot be distinguished.
Both
`SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}_zheng17.loom'` and
`SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}.loom'`
begin and end with the same pattern and snakemake cannot determine if `_zheng17` is part of the wildcard `{loc}` or not.

You can either use what bli described in his comment or change a little bit the output of the either rule. For exemple:

```
rule preprocess_zheng17:
    input:
        loom_file = SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}.loom'
    params:
        transpose = False
    output:
        SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_zheng17_loc{loc}.loom'
    script: 
        "scripts/preprocess_zheng17.py"

rule simulate_data:
    input:
        sample_loom = HDF5_OUTPUT+'/{sample}.loom'
    params:
        group_prob = config['splat_simulate']['group_prob'],
        dropout_present = config['splat_simulate']['dropout_present']
    output:
        SIMULATED_DATA_OUTPUT+'/{sample}_sim_loc{loc}.loom'
    script:
        "scripts/data_simulation.R"
```